# How can I check for a XML file and reading some tags that are not hard-coded (into the program)?

Tags: xml, vb.net

How can I read non-specific tags in XML? Like so:

```
<apps>
  <SomeAppName>
    <version>1</version>
    <location>C:\Program Files\VBNet App\apps\SomeAppName</location>
  </SomeAppName>
  <AnotherAppName>
    <version>5</version>
    <location>C:\Program Files\VBNet App\apps\AnotherAppName</location>
  </AnotherAppName>
</apps>         <!-- added by edit -->
```

The idea is the application to find these tags at it's own, like it isn't told to find exactly `SomeAppName` or `AnotherAppName`, but to find them automatically.

Comment: I'll give you a small hint. It'll be much easier to do what you want if you standardize the `<SomeAppName>` and `<AnotherAppName>` to just `<Application>` and add in a Name element. Also everything in XML is a string. I don't follow your version and location question.

Comment: Using xml linq use following : doc.Descendants().Select(Functon(x) x.Name.LocalName)

Answer (score 1):

To find `SomeAppName` and `AnotherAppName` and others you can use the following XPath:

```
apps/*[version and location]
```

This XPath selects all nodes that have both a `version` child and a `location` child. You can then get their respective names by using the `name()` XPath function on the resulting nodeset.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I will get back to this ASAP! Maybe tomorrow!

Comment: OMG, I am so sorry for getting back to you so late! Anyway, I am struggling with the `name()` part.. what do you mean exactly?

Comment: You can use [`Dim list As IEnumerable(Of XElement) = root.XPathSelectElements("apps/*[version and location]")`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb342176.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-2) to get the nodes (See example in the link). Then you can check their `Name` property if you want their names and access their children with [`.Element("location")`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xcontainer.element.aspx).